# laravel : how to create record that need id from its parent

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I want to make product record that need categories_id, but I can't find a right syntax get id of category from categories table

[heres the entity diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f66lL.png)

relation in product model

```
public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(ProductCategory::class, 'categories_id', 'id');
    }
```

relation in product category model

```
public function products()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Product::class, 'categories_id', 'id');
    }
```

code in product controller:

```
public function makeProduct(Request $request)
    {
        try {
            $request->validate([
                'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
                'price' => ['required', 'double'],
                'description' => ['nullable', 'string', 'max:255'],
                'tags' => ['nullable', 'string', 'max:255'],
            ]);

            Product::create([
                'name' => $request->name,
                'price' => $request->price,
                'description' => $request->name,
                'tags' => $request->tags,
                'categories_id' => category()->id //the error is here
            ]);

            $product = Product::where('name', $request->name)->first();

            return ResponseFormatter::success([
                'message' => 'Product created successfully',
                'product' => $product

            ]);
        } catch (Exception $error) {
            return ResponseFormatter::error([
                'message' => 'Something went wrong',
                'error' => $error

            ]);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you add the error message that you are getting?

It seems that 'category()' is not a function. If you have defined it, please share the code.

Assuming that the `category()` function does not exist, then that must be the error since you are assigning the wrong value to 'categories_id'. You should assign it to `$request->category_id` (or the name of the field that you receive from the request).

Here is an example:

```
            Product::create([
                'name' => $request->name,
                'price' => $request->price,
                'description' => $request->name,
                'tags' => $request->tags,
                'categories_id' => $request->category_id
            ]);
```

---

Just a little advice: when you are defining columns that are going to be foreign keys on a table from the database, remember to define their names in singular. Instead of 'categories_id' it should be 'category_id'. At least, this is how the Laravel standard works.

Comment: Another thing that I forgot to tell you is that you don't need to make a query after creating the product. You can do it just by assigning a variable on Product::create.

Like this: $product = Product::create([...]);